# Can I see columns related to particular datatypes in oracle using query?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I am 90% sure that this is not possible but I need expert advice.

Is this possible to filter out **columns** on the basis of datatypes using any method in `select` list in `oracle` or in any other DBMS.

**eg.**

```
select datatype('DATE') from my_table;
```

To see all the columns in result having datatype `DATE`. I know above query is not possible according to me(specially the `datatype` function :) ) but acknowledge if it is.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, You may not directly run a query containing specific datatypes. However, you can create a procedure to construct a query with table name and datatype as arguments to contain specific columns and return it as a `REF CURSOR`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_getsql(
    p_table_name IN VARCHAR2,
    p_datatype   IN VARCHAR2 ,
    p_query OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
IS
  v_query VARCHAR2(1000) ;
BEGIN
OPEN p_query FOR
  SELECT 'SELECT '
    || LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME,',') WITHIN GROUP (
  ORDER BY column_name ) 
    ||' FROM '||p_table_name query_to_run
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = p_table_name
  AND DATA_TYPE LIKE '%'
    ||p_datatype
    ||'%';
END;
```

You may then call or fetch from this `CURSOR` depending on your requirement.

```
VAR x REFCURSOR;
EXEC proc_getsql('EMPLOYEES','DATE', :x);
PRINT :x;
```

**Output**

```
QUERY_TO_RUN                                  
------------
SELECT HIRE_DATE,DATE_OF_BIRTH FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Comment: welcome..The best way to say thanks in S.O is to mark it as best answer.

Comment: It's not working for me it's returning empty select list in every case

Comment: You probably  don't have access to data dictionary . do a `select * from USER_TAB_COLUMNS` . you should see rows containing your table names. If not , ask / give `grant select any dictionary to yourschemaname` . It could also be possible that you are passing table name and data type  in lower case

Comment: I am having zero rows so I don't have permissions. BTW thanks for your answer.